# Using pd.merge to fill in missing values on left dataframe with a reference table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble using `pd.merge` to fill in some missing data for this data frame I have:

```
fulldf.head(20)

 code    Major_Project_Theme
0   8   Human development
1   11  
2   1   Economic management
3   6   Social protection and risk management
4   5   Trade and integration
5   2   Public sector governance
6   11  Environment and natural resources management
7   6   Social protection and risk management
8   7   Social dev/gender/inclusion
9   7   Social dev/gender/inclusion
10  5   Trade and integration
11  4   Financial and private sector development
12  6   Social protection and risk management
13  6   
14  2   Public sector governance
15  4   Financial and private sector development
16  11  Environment and natural resources management
17  8   
18  10  Rural development
19  7   `
```

Using this reference table:

```
fullgroupeddf = fulldf.groupby(['code', 'Major_Project_Theme']).count()
fullgroupeddf

code    Major_Project_Theme
1   Economic management
10  Rural development
11  Environment and natural resources management
2   Public sector governance
3   Rule of law
4   Financial and private sector development
5   Trade and integration
6   Social protection and risk management
7   Social dev/gender/inclusion
8   Human development
9   Urban development `
```

I tried to use this but didn't work:

```
filleddf = fulldf.merge(fullgroupeddf, how='left', left_on='code', right_on='code')
```

Honestly I have no idea what I'm doing in terms of merge. The idea was to use the ref table i created to fill in the missing values under `Major_Project_Theme` in the first dataframe. What do i put in to my merge statement or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: On what basis do you want to fill the missing values?

Comment: @VikasNS I think each code number is one name in the column Major_Project_Theme (except missing value) so he wants to fill the missing value with the name associated to the code in the row

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in the rows with missing data, you actually have an empty string `''`, you can use `transform(max)` after a `groupby` code such as:

```
filleddf = fulldf.copy() #this is just if you want different dataframes
# filled missing value in the column Major_Project_Theme with:
filleddf['Major_Project_Theme'] = (filleddf.groupby('code')['Major_Project_Theme']
                                            .transform(max))
```

`filleddf` should have all the rows with the good 'Major_Project_Theme' associated to the 'code' filled

Comment: Thanks this did the job. What does `transform(max)` do?

Comment: @vnguyen56 for all the element of the group (for example code = 1), it returns the max value on this group and in this case where it's either `Economic management` or missing value, it returns the not empty strung, meaning `Economic management`. At the end of the day, each time you see code=1, the result will be `Economic management`, replacing the empty strings. Does it make sense? when number are involved, it takes the max the same way if it makes more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the groupby function to group your fulldf by code. Then iterate through each group and keep filling the missing information. Hope this helps.